# Why docker is running just 1 image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new to Docker and i am trying to launch 2 containers first with MongoDB and the second one with Mongo-Express. Container with MongoDB is mounted but container with Mongo-Express, is not.

When i execute `sudo docker ps` all i have is:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORT                                            NAMES
413b5952f5e1   mongo     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   27 minutes ago   Up 22 minutes   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp, :::27017->27017/tcp   docker-node_mongodb_1
```

Here is content of my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    networks:
      - mongo-network
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    depends_on: 
      - 'mongodb'
    ports:
      - 8080:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
    networks:
      - mongo-network
networks: 
  mongo-network:
```

Comment: Maybe the `mongo-express` container crashed. You can check by running `docker-compose logs`.

Comment: Check status of all containers, including crashed ones with `sudo docker ps -a`

Comment: Yep. Its crushed. Complains about being un-able ti connect to mogo server

Comment: If you run `docker ps -a` you will see every containers in your docker; for your container 
crash issues, try running your `docker-compose up` without `-d` option so it will show you debug informations while creating/starting your service containers

Comment: What exactly do the error logs say? It could be that the mongo container isn't fully ready to accept connections by the time the mongo-express container tries to connect (even though the `depends_on` is set, this can still be an issue).